# Get google doc description using googleapis in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am exploring google api to find out a file description, which is a short summary of google drive file.

[image]

So I have came up with this code:

```
  const {google} = require('googleapis');

  const docs = google.docs({
    version: "v1",
  });

  // set keys and docid
  // clientEmail, privateKey, documentid

  const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(clientEmail, null, privateKey, scopes);

  const response = await docs.documents.get({
    auth: jwt,
    documentId: documentId,
  });
```

The response returning an [object](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Document) but it is does not contain description. Any ideas how to find that through the 'googleapis' ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Docs API has this option. However, I know you can get that information using Drive API with the method `Files: get` and using the parameter `'fields':'description'` or you can use the method `Files: list` with the parameter `'fields': 'files(description)'` if you wanted to list the files with the description already on it.

**Method Files: list**

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      "corpora": "user",
      "q": "'folder_ID' in parents",
      "supportsAllDrives": true,
      "supportsTeamDrives": true,
      "fields": "files(description, id, name)"
    })
```

**Method Files:get**

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        'fileId': 'file_ID',
        'fields':'description, id, name'
    })
```

**Reference:**

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: If this answered your question @sreginogemoh, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)